# YouTube videos not playing

Tags: youtube

I recently means TODAY installed Ubuntu along with Windows 7 means this is a dual boot system.

So this is the case

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 and than upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 and after installing the updates , Youtube videos are not playing . I'm using CHROME as my primary browser. Flash player is installed by default but still i uninstall it and re install it just to make sure everything is ok. But still videos are playing.

Chrome Version 19.0.1084.56

Comment: Adobe flash player is bundled with Google Chrome by default, but isn't pre-installed in Ubuntu. Can you elaborate on the part where you uninstalled and reinstalled it.

Comment: Ya it is , as i said it was not working even before RE-INSTALLATION   I re-installed it from Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Again, how did you uninstall the flash player bundled with Google Chrome? As for your info, the Software Center won't affect it. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package.  It installs all the non-free media codecs that allows you to play videos or music.  Search for that in the software center, and then install it.

You can install Flash and `ubuntu-restricted-extras` together if you want.